# My javafx app throws an error when trying to connect with the database

Tags: java, mysql, database, maven, javafx

Good day, people. I've come to crash into an error that I can't find solution for yet, so I really need your help.

The program is as it follows: A desktop app made with Javafx (Maven) and Scenebuilder, that will allow the user to add, modify and erase different plants that will later be stored in a database to be shown as a list in a different screen.

Now the problem comes when I try to start the connection. The error is the following:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/F:/2DAM/BioGuardian/BioGuardian/target/classes/com/bioguardian/bioguardian/main.fxml:15

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:944)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:981)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:755)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at com.bioguardian.bioguardian/com.bioguardian.bioguardian.App.start(App.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:72)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:939)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:259)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:408)
    at com.bioguardian.bioguardian/com.bioguardian.bioguardian.HerbDAO.conectar(HerbDAO.java:20)
    at com.bioguardian.bioguardian/com.bioguardian.bioguardian.AppCtrl.<init>(AppCtrl.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    ... 20 more
Exception running application com.bioguardian.bioguardian.App

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The files that error call out are these:

R:

```
package com.bioguardian.bioguardian.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class R {
    public static InputStream getImage(String name) {
        return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images" + File.separator + name);
    }

    public static InputStream getProperties(String name) {
        return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("configuration" + File.separator + name);
    }

    public static URL getUI(String name) {
        return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("bioguardian" + File.separator + name);
    }
}
```

HerbDAO:

```
private Connection conexion;
    //Con esta función cogemos los datos de database.properties y los usamos para
    //generar la conexión sin tener que andar haciendolo a mano
    public void conectar() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
        Properties configuration = new Properties();
        configuration.load(R.getProperties("database.properties")); //This is the line that provokes the error
        String host = configuration.getProperty("host");
        String port = configuration.getProperty("port");
        String name = configuration.getProperty("name");
        String username = configuration.getProperty("username");
        String password = configuration.getProperty("password");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + name + "?serverTimezone=UTC",
                username, password);
    }
```

And AppCtrl:

```
private final HerbDAO herbDAO;

    public AppCtrl(){
        //Arrancamos conexion con la BBDD
        herbDAO = new HerbDAO();
        try{
            herbDAO.conectar();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    }
```

I have tried deleting and making it from scratch. Without these functions, the app works but of course, doesn't has a Database connection. I have also tried to change R's definition for the database.properties, but it didn't work either.

I simply cannot understand what kind of problem can these functions be provoking, so I would thank any available help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I suggest reading [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/685806)

Comment: Probably your `R.getProperties` method is returning null, meaning the resource you are looking up can’t be found. You should not be looking up a resource using a file separator as the resource might be in a jar, not a file. The use of the context classloader is strange. Follow the [guide for looking up resources for JavaFX apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other) (including the troubleshooting section).

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null

...

at com.bioguardian.bioguardian/com.bioguardian.bioguardian.HerbDAO.conectar(HerbDAO.java:20)

at com.bioguardian.bioguardian/com.bioguardian.bioguardian.AppCtrl.(AppCtrl.java:70)

...

You need to learn how to read a stacktrace.